# SQL query ignores "not between"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data source like following

[image]

If I ran the following sql query it removes all the records with "Seg Type" MOD and ignores the Fnn range given.

```
select * from NpsoQueue
where SegmentType not in ('MOD')
and Fnn not between 0888452158 and 0888452158
```

I want the query to consider both conditions. So, if I ran the query it should remove only the first record

Comment: Change `AND Fnn ...` to `OR Fnn....`

Comment: in between condition you are putting same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic in your `where` clause is incorrect

Use

```
select * from NpsoQueue
where NOT (
    SegmentType = 'MOD'
    and Fnn between '0888452158' and '0888452158'
    )
```

Also, a number with a leading zero is a string literal so you need to put single quotes around it to preserve the leading zero and stop implicit casts happening

As mentioned by @TriV you could also use `OR`. These are fundamental boolean logic concepts, i.e. not related to SQL Server or databases